# separate number from String containing spaces and hyphens in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am developing C# MVC application. I got an account name and its code from one field from the view but I have to segregate them for storing them in database. I have used Regular Expression and successfully separated the code from rest of the string. But in the string part I can only get the string before the space or hyphen. My Regex is:

```
string numberPart = Regex.Match(s, @"\d+").Value;
string alphaPart = Regex.Match(s, @"[a-zA-Z]+\s+").Value;
d.code = numberPart;
d.name = alphaPart;
```

"2103010001 - SALES - PACKING SERV - MUTTON ( 1F )"
this is my complete string from the view. When I used the above Regex for separating code and description, I get the following,

```
numberPart = 2103010001
alphaPart = SALES
```

What I want is:

```
numberPart = 2103010001
alphaPart = SALES - PACKING SERV - MUTTON ( 1F )
```

What would be the appropriate expression to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second regex, you essentially want "everything after (and including) the first letter". Thus you can simply try

```
string alphaPart = Regex.Match(s, @"[a-zA-Z].*").Value;
```

If you want to be more specific, you can restrict the "after" part to just the characters you expect, maybe

```
string alphaPart = Regex.Match(s, @"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 ()-]*").Value;
```

but you still need the leading `[a-zA-Z]` because otherwise you'd match the number part too.

Answer (score 1):

Just do splitting accoring to the first `-` character.

```
Regex.Split(input, @"(?<=^[^-]*?)\s*-\s*");
```

[DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5e%5b%5e-%5d*%3f)%5cs*-%5cs*&i=2103010001+-+SALES+-+PACKING+SERV+-+MUTTON+(+1F+))